# U.K. Nest E Installation

Tags: thermostat

Currently an ideal logic c30 combi with a wireless thermostat on the wall. I took off the cover of the wireless controller and can’t work out the wiring to go in the heatlink. The app guides me through and I can’t get the stuff to match up. I’ve attached images. Any advice is really appreciated.

[image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]

Comment: Advice? Pay a certified electrician that knows how to install it correctly and safely according to local electrical code and legislation.

Comment: Have you tried to use [the instructions](https://nest.com/support/images/misc-assets/Nest-Thermostat-Installation-Guide-UK.pdf)?  They are very thorough, and if you are unable to follow them to connect the four available wires, you should follow the advice in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

A and B goes into the C and NO contacts of the nest-e, L and N should be capped because not used by that thermostat (that is fed by two AA cells).

Pay attention that L and N are at mains voltage, switch the main switch first at your consumer unit.